# RuntimeWarning:You're running the worker with superuser privileges:this is absolutely not recommended

Tags: redis, celery

I am using django+celery+redis,celery==4.4.0 in local it is working fine but when I am dockerizing it , I am getting the above error.

I am using following commands to run in local as well as inside container

```
**CMDs**
celery -A nrn worker -l info 
docker run -d -p 6379:6379 redis
flower -A nrn --port=5555
```

Any help is highly appreciated

*settings.py**

```
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'

CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.environ.get('redis', 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/')
```

Answer (score 39):

Take a look in the [documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html#running-the-worker-with-superuser-privileges-root). It's a warning, though, not an error (see the [code](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/platforms.py#L789)). Running Celery under root is an error only when you allow pickle serialization which is not enabled by default (see [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/configuration.html#accept-content)).

However, it's still the best practice to run Celery with lower privileges. In Docker (with Debian based image), I choose to run Celery under `nobody`:`nogroup`. I use this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.6

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /srv/celery

COPY ./app app
COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
COPY ./celery.sh celery.sh

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir \
    -r /tmp/requirements.txt

VOLUME ["/var/log/celery", "/var/run/celery"]

CMD ["./celery.sh"]
```

where `celery.sh` looks as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mkdir -p /var/run/celery /var/log/celery
chown -R nobody:nogroup /var/run/celery /var/log/celery

exec celery --app=app worker \
            --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/var/log/celery/worker-example.log \
            --statedb=/var/run/celery/worker-example@%h.state \
            --hostname=worker-example@%h \
            --queues=celery.example -O fair \
            --uid=nobody --gid=nogroup
```

Comment: Are there permissions implications to this? Does this mean Celery isn't going to be able to do certain things in an application because of its lower permissions levels?

Comment: No, Celery is going to do fine as it doesn't need superuser permissions to do its job. It's just a good practise that services (especially those exposed to the network) drop superuser permissions once they set up everything they need (e.g. binding to a port < 1024). That way, the security risks are minimized.